# Extending existing Swing look and feels with custom JComponents

Tags: java, swing, custom-component, look-and-feel, uimanager

I'm writing a custom `JComponent`, that should look differently for different look and feels. I intend to have different `ComponentUi` classes at least for the `WindowsLookAndFeel`, the `MetalLookAndFeel` and for the `MotifLookAndFeel`.

Now, while this task seems easy enough, I couldn't find out how to easily extend an existing look and feel with my custom `ComponentUi` classes.

How would I go about registering the correct `ComponentUi` for the different look and feels? Is this possible at all? If not, what is the preferred way to write a custom component for different look and feels?

---

To be a bit more specific, at the moment I'm overriding `JComponent#updateUI` in my custom component to set the different `ComponentUi` instances:

```
@Override
public void updateUI() {
    LookAndFeel feel = UIManager.getLookAndFeel();
    if (feel instanceof WindowsLookAndFeel) {
        setUI(MyWindowsCustomUi.createUI(this));
    } else if (feel instanceof MotifLookAndFeel) {
        setUI(MyMotivCustomUi.createUI(this));
    } else if (feel instanceof MetalLookAndFeel) {
        setUI(MyMetalCustomUi.createUI(this));
    } else{
        setUI(MyBasicCustomUi.createUI(this));
    }
}
```

But this approach seems to entirely defeat the purpose and usefulness of look and feels. I'd like to be able to change this to the following:

```
public void updateUI() {
    setUI((MyCustomUi)UIManager.getUI(this));
}
```

And this should set the correct subclass of `MyCustomUi` for the current look and feel.

I know, that I could easily achieve this by creating custom subclasses of each supported `LookAndFeel`, that register the corresponding `ComponentUi` during e.g. `BasicLookAndFeel#initComponentDefaults(UIDefaults)` - but this is not what I want to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want it or not - you *have* to register your custom UIs somehow with the UIManager, how else could it know about them ;-)

What you don't need, though, is a custom subclass of the supported LAFs: you can register them manually (and update the registration when the LAF is changed, that is you'll need a propertyChangeListener on the UIManager to be notified in such a case).

Assuming a JCustom with a classID of "CustomUI" and ui implementations following the usual conventions (that is BasicCustomUI, WindowsCustomUI ... ) the registration would be something like:

```
 String prefix = UIManager.getLookAndFeel().getID();
 UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("CustomUI", myUIPackage + "." + prefix + CustomUI);
```

Note that the custom ui needs a static createUI which returns an instance of the ui:

```
 public static ComponentUI createUI(JComponent comp) {
     return new BasicCustomUI(); 
 }
```

and the component needs to publish its uiClassID, lookup and set its ui:

```
@Override
public String getUIClassID() {
    return "CustomUI";
}

@Override
public void updateUI() {
    setUI(UIManager.getUI(this));
}
```

The benefit of using SwingX is to provide the infrastructure to automagically register custom components. You'll need an additional class - CustomAddon - which provides the per-LAF configuration and the custom component has to contribute that addon:

```
// in JCustom

static {
    LookAndFeelAddons.contribute(new CustomAddon());
}

// in CustomAddon

@Override
protected void addBasicDefaults(LookAndFeelAddons addon, DefaultsList defaults) {
    super.addBasicDefaults(addon, defaults);
    defaults.add("CustomUI",
            "mypackage.BasicCustomUI");
}

@Override
protected void addMacDefaults(LookAndFeelAddons addon, DefaultsList defaults) {
    super.addMacDefaults(addon, defaults);
    defaults.add("CustomUI",
            "mypackage.MacCustomUI");
}

//... similar methods for all supported LAFs
```

Comment: Thank you very much - I registered the custom component using `LookAndFeelAddons.contribute()` from SwingX and it works like a charm.